# Creating self-signed root CA using MacOS Keychain

Tags: certificate-authority, openssl, macos, keychain

I'd like to use MacOS keychain to create a basic Root CA, which will be able to sign CSRs and/or Intermediate CA which will be able to do that.

For knowledge purpose, I'd like to create a Root, and Intermediate then our common internal SSL certificates, but IRL, only a root and some leaves are enough.

I'm trying many combinations of usage for the root and for the leaves. On MacOS, I just need to trust the Root certificate and the descendants are trusted (which is totally normal). But on Windows, no matter how I trust the Root, leaves are always flagged as untrusted, saying something like "This certificate is untrusted because the signing certificate can't issue certificates", even if I tick EVERY usage possible.

As an example, here is the **RootCA.pem**:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Here is the leaf certificate.pem:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And here is the leaf certificate private key (decrypted):

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: lan.oph.ovh
    localKeyID: E7 36 A4 85 FC 43 2A F9 79 01 36 37 80 BB 00 38 30 74 0E 47 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDU4qCtqZTIQxoH
JYmrq9cdHWfdSanypoT6IWAkhTin5z2N9Uwm5G0QJxIl6Mggqn7S6bmsIkB4U1Kb
IuYwan7OOYtNTJKuuX9kkqHAuiXEkIrrww4knoJUQlqaY7p0DnlEiC6QelGxSeVR
275WlAHt2wqt4bjhvbeOlrnDeXgeSdvuUbE49eMDJryR+JmU5tsGd7XF04tB+N0e
qlS+Mke/S5qOr5H9iegfsN+ndRU1nitbAC0dwls6ksBqbhwVywPL6kbWeDbKvK6n
58YrQeO9IeGPpWMImpnKwkYXfMgXAS6Cg3SWIIroawzq8zl+bQVsQWgu+eut891Y
/eARx7HnAgMBAAECggEBAJLwFf2oBjSv9CAorbybcG/9IvqfZLlCbJiFPuoWNgPW
XStFu5lAo3K5tRILeU7qv3zurCR+w8cJpAPGc+HJL9tB5r+k8b299YtClnkDQxxI
tEqEqJdn/QcRgZ385e5DKzq9UH6Snx5ipfD5Xog9wpMdVGKuYUEXBMJbkL62cc1c
5JraBNvUPDoIkLI1fyBz2ZEc9Iz4wweSk2IldPCXXHmL2OLDSDwsl9HpJoMJTt8S
PaWTOOBrCBtW9if6vvwZDPOpdHISdfhg/N+ifE0eYn2s8cxPs/9Y1dDo2L5gS8re
pOB4LAaeOos4mvQ8808HLX8Y9M+iuM3Qr8ToiGvkbTkCgYEA+EPHTfkllDUn2fel
6+zxJv4omKZupJ3Bvx/g+AjFBnAzkMVkcuhRA7B5dlBq3f2N1QFBBJJnkmF7z3Mu
IAXTM5MOuwqgywApA/voK0p5ZragP9WZR/5+SakWeVF+Vk1Zvu816ppLBXW64H6+
t+YRqa1KYAVj8xbgATxGb81QmPsCgYEA24SnSTBbhvMMaZoUGecIf29Pxx4+WAkh
Dq1Q0V1CH/zBIYvgnN1cI4E/TFcrzHhxmxtb5B6PYpZfD59tzvbKGNPL64hAqWwg
4IFuvNpw2aJptQGz9D6Vu61kAe4m/5Hw6wcJN3o73pMGV3CuoyHqYj85vqCasbFP
vOitYUpaDwUCgYBfQsqn/bDQtLDM7zyoUWubFa0IHdyYp7vfFWFiayMGvGjc5REN
El17t+xzXJoVAiS5FdkX4wGA5oz2ZfDN8s4+nO/rD0Hxguc6Ex/b9KCuq+bDd7dw
K5PTueDYvk9m2BlWrT0X/wpIVwtU9u1BbTNb0xWV0JuwfBeKAdHZNoP1nwKBgQCf
YlGT8miCMzZv9k9h/z1MSaXDDVJ22SoHXg+v8+ZvEzWnBciwHIkpvk4XP7OtYkYa
OGMf3pB9JHEhBsDT5JwYKq+E9Aj++mNknpWoyXHmkuXtZq8iR86v1dUnEaN/LJeg
DhvDDB0sHdQc6NPj3lwvuXhT0IiBPByJLOe2HCYHgQKBgDNRAJ4C1SAAW3XXnoCL
kjnvaXk0plj7Sh1JfZiipZun2Gl99JX68aNh+5bnm5Yq+jQHKHmAQfHnXW4Nyjk7
vmlI+LGZvwVkKQn6xORWNz3T0CUD9MHNCWN5CNL6HJJ3mBYDqpjC5n2i10/tF2Jv
WtTYDNeQf1HnCLuoDSV1y/nB
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Can someone help me understand why this certificate can't be trusted on Windows and what did I possibly miss please?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be valid to me. Windows does not complain about the leaf certificate if I install the CA. XCA also confirms the leaf as trusted.

Are you using browser that uses its own list of trusted roots, like Firefox?

Comment: Now you mention it... I do. Without knowing it, I tried with FF (so, I trusted the root on the wrong store) and with chrome. Does chrome also have its own store?

Comment: @Max13 No, chrome should use the root store of the OS according to their policy: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy#TOC-Removal-of-Trust